# Any imagery from Shuttle Columbia's SILTS pod on the internet?

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry, imaging, shuttle-columbia

(Inspired by [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/what-effect-if-any-would-leaving-the-cargo-bay-doors-open-have-had-during-a-sh))

One of the distinguishing features of Shuttle Columbia was its Shuttle Infrared Leeside Temperature Sensing (SILTS) pod. This was an experiment that took infrared imagery of the left wing and parts of the fuselage during entry.  (It was deactivated long before the STS-107 accident so there was no data from it contributing to the accident investigation.)

[image]

Is there any imagery from this experiment available online?  I found [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuoI3Gl43QAhWLr1QKHVP-BzkQFghJMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.37.8683%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNHCmZzbgOIAkg0sRwXRXMK9yuhU9w&sig2=_671qiGsp2OJdiA5pkZEGw) (warning, pdf) that uses some results, but no actual imagery.

Comment: [Another image of the pod](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/A31.jpg) from [here](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2011/02/space-shuttle-columbia-a-new-beginning-and-vision/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia has one image that is attributed to the SILTS pod:

[image: SILTS IR Image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SILTS_Image.jpg)

Unfortunately, the metadata doesn't give any clue as to where it came from, or where more might be found.

I just happened to be reading the [STS-28 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-28), noticed the image, and remembered this question.

Comment: Certainly looks like the correct viewing angle.  Thanks, great find.

Comment: While it appears as of the right-most "hot spot" is the leading edge of the port wing, one one wonders what caused the left-most such "hot spot."

Comment: That is the gap between the inboard and outboard elevons.