# How would the space shuttle fare without payload doors?

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry

If the space shuttle had the doors locked open, blown off, or otherwise unable to close, would it be able to re-enter and land somewhat intact? Was there any procedures in place on the off chance this could have happened?

There is the question [What effect (if any) would leaving the cargo bay doors open have had during a shuttle reentry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/what-effect-if-any-would-leaving-the-cargo-bay-doors-open-have-had-during-a-sh) about using the doors as radiators during decent, however, it doesn't describe what would actually happen without the door panels.

Comment: You're right that the other question doesn't ask the same one you are, but the answer there answers your question.

Comment: Amusingly it was also a big problem if the doors would not open, the thermal radiators are inside the doors, and if they could not open, it was reenter soonest!

Comment: Answers to the suggested duplicate question explain that if the doors were closed and even a single door latch gang was not fastened during entry the vehicle would have been damaged. If more than one latch gang was failed an EVA would be done to install tools to hold the latches closed.  No analysis was done for worse cases.  So the answer to your question is "No" and it's explained in detail in the answers to the suggested duplicate. If this gets reopened, I'll happily copy in the same answer but not sure how that helps anybody.