# Did every shuttle flight after STS-5 carry EMUs onboard?

Tags: space-shuttle, eva

STS-5 is the first shuttle mission to carry Extravehicular Mobility Units onboard during the Space Shuttle program. Due to various issues happened during STS-5, the first extravehicular activity occurred during STS-6.

The NASA Office of Inspector General's report [NASA's Management And Development Of Spacesuits](https://oig.nasa.gov/docs/IG-17-018.pdf) stated that two EMUs were lost in STS-107. This suggests that the shuttle carries EMUs even for mission not planned for EVA.

Therefore, does every shuttle mission after STS-5 carry EMUs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, every shuttle flight after STS-5 carried EMUs, because EVA repair was counted on as a level of redundancy for several critical failures (most of which never happened, but that's not the point).

[image]
(Source - [Generic Shuttle Flight rules](https://archive.org/details/flight_rules_generic))

Here are some of the contingency EVAs:

- Stow the radiators
- Close the Payload Bay Doors
- Stow the Remote Manipulator System
- Stow the Ku-band Antenna ([this one did actually happen once](https://books.google.com/books?id=yzkpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=stow%20the%20ku%20band%20antenna%20eva&source=bl&ots=9yCr2uBhHc&sig=ACfU3U3x7NvdgAsE-2hyLMWXB__jCt_JKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA5c-5g5zgAhWuna0KHVdkC80Q6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=stow%20the%20ku%20band%20antenna%20eva&f=false))
- Close the External Tank Umbilical Doors
- Repair the tile (After STS-107)
- Basically stow anything that would prevent the payload bay doors from
  closing

Here's a list from the [EVA Checklist](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492872main_EVA_G_H_20.pdf) (these are generic, there could be additional flight specific ones):
[image]

I forgot about the 96 bolt EVA - that one is for if the Orbiter got stuck on the docking system! And yes, they would have had to release 96 bolts (and cut some supply tubing as well...)

[image]

The ET door one was out there too. They would have had to stuff clothes in a duffle bag and throw it through the gap between the inner and outer elevons to get a line to travel to the area on.... (this was written before the Orbiter Boom Sensor System (OBSS) was flown, that would have made it a heck of a lot easier).

[image]

This graphic shows how using the OBSS would have made it easier to access the ET door area.

[image]

Comment: *They had to stuff clothes in a duffle bag and throw it through the gap between the inner and outer elevons to get a line to travel to the area on* WOW.

Comment: Which mission was the "ET Door" mission? I've never heard of that, and googling the keywords leads me only to this post.

Comment: @dotancohen It never happened, like most contingency procedures. I should have written it as 'they would of had to...' When I get on a real pc I'll edit for clarity - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is why I love this site...!

Comment: A little more information on STS-49 with the Ku-band antenna problem: https://www.scribd.com/document/52710703/STS-49-Space-Shuttle-Mission-Report (page 17 in the original document, PDF page 27)

Comment: @BretCopeland that was one of the more interesting missions to be sure.